Fetching Hashtag Content with Instagram Graph API Returns Inconsistent Status Codes
I'm working with the Instagram Graph API to fetch content associated with specific hashtags. I've already set up my access token and business ID, and my code is intended to retrieve posts using the related hashtag. However, I'm encountering an issue where the API responses are inconsistent: sometimes I receive a 200 status code, indicating success, but at other times I get a 400 status code. Occasionally, the response message is "sorry, content is unavailable." I believe my setup for the hashtag ID is correct but I'm unsure if I'm missing any required permissions or if there's another issue at play.
Are there specific permissions required for fetching hashtag content that I might be missing?
Could the inconsistency in the API responses be related to the way I've set up the hashtag ID, or is it likely due to another issue?
Has anyone else experienced similar inconsistencies when using the Instagram Graph API for hashtag content, and how were you able to resolve it?
What I've tried:
Double-checking the access token and business ID to ensure they're correctly set up.
Verifying the hashtag ID is correct and relates to the content I'm trying to fetch.
Looking for documentation on required permissions specifically for hashtag content but haven't found clear guidelines.

The requirements are listed under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-hashtag-search#reading

'Occasionally, the response message is "sorry, content is unavailable."' - maybe that's simply all the API is willing to give you at this point - due to general overload or whatever. So program defensively, and figure out how your app should react in that situation.
